# Can't set FullControl on directory

Tags: c#, security, windows-7

I'm trying to set FullControl for Everyone programmatically on a Windows 7 box with no luck.

```
var dirSec = dir.GetAccessControl();
var fsar = new FileSystemAccessRule(
    "Everyone",
    FileSystemRights.FullControl,
    InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
    PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, 
    AccessControlType.Allow);

dirSec.AddAccessRule(fsar);
dir.SetAccessControl(dirSec);
```

This adds some permissions for the Everyone group (List and Read), but not full control. If I edit the security permissions using Explorer I can set it to FullControl. Any ideas why it's failing? There are no error messages from my attempts.

Comment: My guess is that your application's process isn't running as elevated, so you don't have the appropriate permissions to modify access levels. Have you tried running the app as Administrator (right-click on the icon, and select "Run As Administrator" from the context menu)?

Comment: App is running as elevated - which is why I can't figure out why it can't create the full control permissions.

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine:

```
    string path = @"C:\test";
    DirectorySecurity ds = Directory.GetAccessControl(path);
    ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
    Directory.SetAccessControl(path, ds);
```

If that does not work then it seems that your application does not have rights to give that kind access rule. Try to implement impersonation. Here is a sample: [WindowsIdentity Impersonation using C# Code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabhkv/archive/2008/05/29/windowsidentity-impersonation-using-c-code.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (FileSystemRights permission in Enum.GetValues(typeof(FileSystemRights)))
{
    myDirectorySecurity.AddAccessRule(
        new FileSystemAccessRule(user,
                                 permission,
                                 InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit |
                                     InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit |
                                     InheritanceFlags.None,
                                 PropagationFlags.None,
                                 AccessControlType.Allow));
}
```